# Why did my countdown clock stop counting?

Tags: javascript, html

Let me preface this with I'm pretty clueless about JavaScript..

So for example, I just want to link to a countdown that will count down until when a particular server is open.

I used https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp to make the countdown and modified it so that it uses the server time instead of the client time.

```
var serverNow =  new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Seoul"});

var tomorrowKR = new Date(serverNow);
tomorrowKR.setDate(tomorrowKR.getDate()+1)
tomorrowKR.setHours(18,0,0,0)

var countDownDateKR = tomorrowKR.getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date(serverNow).getTime();
  var distanceKR = countDownDateKR - now;
  var hoursKR = Math.floor((distanceKR % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutesKR = Math.floor((distanceKR % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var secondsKR = Math.floor((distanceKR % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("ASIAServer").innerHTML = "The KR Server is currently CLOSED, but will open again in " + hoursKR + "h " + minutesKR + "m " + secondsKR + "s (6 PM KST)" ;
  }, 1000);
}
```

The error seems to be in the line

```
var now = new Date(serverNow).getTime();
```

if I remove the "serverNow" and just let it roll as the client time, it will count down. 
Changing it to the serverNow, it displays the correct countdown time, but the actual countdown action stops.

What's going on with this?

Comment: Have you checked console for errors?

Comment: _“and modified it so that it uses the server time”_ - and where exactly did you do that? Not with `var serverNow =  new Date().toLocaleString(…)`, that is still absolutely, purely client-side.

Comment: @Justinas Yup, empty :/

Comment: What is your timezone offset?

Comment: @CBroe I see that, ya, but really all I want is a way for people to see when it's availiable at like 6PM KST or whatever. Wouldn't that be enough for a countdown?

Comment: @RobG UTC+9 so -540

Comment: @RobG I actually tried to handle that by checking the "server time". If the server time is before the first server then tomorrow is technically today. it seems to work even when I manually change my time zones to anything.
What do you mean by them both being constants? Aren't they both constants as seen here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_countdown

Comment: @AON—you will still get weird errors around daylight saving changeovers.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi remove the `serverNow` from the `var now = new Date(serverNow).getTime();` on line 16. It starts ticking again for me

Comment: @RobG Yeah I figured as much.. Luckily this is just a temporary thing that I can stop worrying about very soon! Hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `new Date(serverNow)` inside your `setInterval`, the value does not update because `serverNow` does not change. `serverNow` is a fixed string that keeps whatever value it had when the page was first loaded. For `now` to update with every interval, you need to get the latest server time:

```
now = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/Seoul"})).getTime();
```

Definitely not the prettiest code in the world. You should know that working with dates and timezones in vanilla Javascript is always messy. A lot of people use Moment.js to save significant headache.